# What's the windows message of ID 96/0x0060?

Tags: c++, windows

I found a strange crash in my application when in the message loop using PeekMessage.The application is built with VS2013 and runs on Windows 11. The application doesn't crash
in Windows 10 but only in Windows 11. The call stack when it crashed is as follows:

```
KernelBase.dll!RaiseFailFastException()

CoreMessaging.dll!CFlat::Abandonment::FailWithException(struct _EXCEPTION_RECORD *,struct _CONTEXT *)

CoreMessaging.dll!CFlat::Abandonment::FailWithHR(int,void *,int)

CoreMessaging.dll!AlpcConnection::Callback_ProcessIncoming()

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Messaging::CrossProcessReceivePort$AlpcReceiveSource::OnReceive()

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::OffThreadReceiver::Callback_OnDispatch() 

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::EventLoop::Callback_RunCoreLoop()

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::OnUserDispatch()

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::DoWork()

CoreMessaging.dll!Microsoft::CoreUI::Dispatch::UserAdapter::WindowProc()

user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()

user32.dll!CallWindowProcAorW(__int64 (*)(struct HWND__ *,unsigned int,unsigned __int64,__int64),struct HWND__ *,enum _WM_VALUE,unsigned __int64,__int64,int)

user32.dll!CallWindowProcA()

mfc120.dll!00007ffbc54c625b()

user32.dll!UserCallWinProcCheckWow()

user32.dll!DispatchClientMessage()

user32.dll!__fnDWORD()

ntdll.dll!00007ffc197676a4()

win32u.dll!00007ffc16e413b4()

user32.dll!_PeekMessage()

user32.dll!PeekMessageA()
```

By the disassemble code I find the message ID which CallWindowProc dispatches is 96(decimal)/0x0060,but I can't find what this message ID is. Dose anyone know about this message or some suggestions about this crash?

Comment: `PROCESS_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` https://james.darpinian.com/decoder/?q=0x0060

Comment: @Genjutsu No, seems incorrect

Comment: I found the message 96 is sent to a window which class name is "SystemUserAdapterWindowClass". It seems a system window that I didn't create it. Does anyone know what this window is?

Comment: There's no official window message 0x60 in Windows, it maybe some internal thing or it comes from from somewhere else, like a memory corruption, since you're running with C++, you can a priori mess with your process quite easily. Do you have some reproducible code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Given that this issue is specific to Windows 11 and doesn't occur in Windows 10, it's possible that there may be some compatibility or behavioral changes in the Windows 11 environment that are triggering this crash. Try to update your VS2013 first, if still not working and try to update your application's dependencies. Let's see what happens.

Comment: You should create a memory dump and check the Exception record in Windbg. This will display the full HResult error code in the Exception Record. Actually there will be two . The first is HRESULT, the second is the original error code.

Answer (score 1):

### ALPC is failing on a message it receives from another process

ALPC is a Windows IPC mechanism that is used internally in Windows. It has been reverse-engineered but using any API gleaned from reverse-engineering would make any program fragile to ALPC changes (say from Windows 10 to 11). ;-)

I found this post helpful in getting up to speed on it.

https://csandker.io/2022/05/24/Offensive-Windows-IPC-3-ALPC.html

Comment: Yes, ALPC is a suspicious thing for the crash. I notice the "AlpcReceiveSource::OnReceive" line in the callstack after your mension of ALPC. I'll dig into ALPC trying to find a solution. Thank you!